# Double loop that finds the bottom and top of range in workbook and then finds range for next section in workbook that meets the criteria

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim top As Integer
Dim bot As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim Copyrange As String

For i = 2 To LastRow
    If wbkCurBook.Sheets("August FMR").Cells(i, "B").Value = "CASE TOTAL" Then
        wbkCurBook.Sheets("August FMR").Cells(i + 1, "F").Value = "OPEN LINE ITEMS"
        wbkCurBook.Sheets("August FMR").Cells(i + 1, "G").Select
        For t = 1 To i
            If wbkCurBook.Sheets("August FMR").Cells(t, "B").Value = "CSE" And IsEmpty(wbkCurBook.Sheets("August FMR").Cells(i + 1, "G").Value) Then
                    top = t + 1
                    bot = i - 1
                    Let Copyrange = "J" & top & ":" & "K" & bot
                    n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wbkCurBook.Sheets("August FMR").Range(Copyrange), ">" & 0)
                    wbkCurBook.Sheets("August FMR").Cells(i + 1, "G").Value = n
            End If
        Next t
    End If
Next i
```

This code is looping through a sheet with 4 thousand rows with some blanks in between which mark the different sections. What I want the code to do is go through each different section and find the nonzero cells of each section by finding the top and bottom row of the each section. Currently the code does not break, but it is not outputting the correct amount of nonzero cells. The variable top is staying at "2" for some reason which outputs the wrong numbers. I need top to find the top of the range, but its currently only finding the first section and saving that range.

Comment: Look at `Areas`.

Comment: @sjr im looking at Areas and it sort of makes sense but Im not entirey sure how it could work with my code

Comment: Combine it with `specialcells` and you can loop through each block - each area will be the cells between the blanks.

Comment: @SJR would it be this?

Comment: @sjr would i only need one for each statement like this? For Each area In sh.Range("A1:S" & lr).SpecialCells(x1CellTypeConstants,23).Areas

Comment: Think that should do it, depending on how your data looks exactly.

Comment: The first time you go through the outer loop, i =2, and you are only doing something if the value of cell B2 is "CASE_TOTAL".

The first time you go through the inner loop, t = 1
The next time t=2, and you are doing this test:

If wbkCurBook.Sheets("August FMR").Cells(t, "B").Value = "CSE" ....

But, we already already know that Cell B2 has to be "CASE_TOTAL", so this test will not be met, and the inner loop will never progress beyond t=2, and "top" will never be more than 2.

Have you got the columns mixed up?

Comment: Since it definitely is a **work**sheet, you could use the following two lines before the loop: `Dim ws As Worksheet` and `Set ws = wbkCurBook.Worksheets("August FMR")`. Then you can replace all the occurrences of `wbkCurBook.Sheets("August FMR")` in the loop with `ws` to make it more readable. You should explain what the strings "CASE TOTAL", "OPEN LINE ITEMS" and "CSE" are supposed to signify and what you are doing in each range when you find it. Posting an image might certainly help.

Comment: @VBasic2008 CASE TOTAL is at the bottom of each section and totals numbers in rows. OPEN LINE ITEMS is 1 row below CASE TOTAL and is supposed to perform another calculation of number of cells that are nonzero. CSE is one of the headers at the top of each section. My idea was to find the top of the range use CSE and the bottom of the range using CASE TOTAL

Comment: That makes sense, but I don't understand what you are going to do with each range after you have defined it?